# Is there any fast way to search whether something exists in a NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, search, sorting, nsarray

Currently, If I want to search whether an object is in a NSArray(not sorted) or not. I have to loop over the array and check each object until I found one that match my expectation.

I doubt it's performance even if the check is only a if  statement.

To improve the search performance is there any provided solution?

Or I can only sort the array some way and use some way like binary-search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorting then searching will take more time than a loop iterating over each element of the array since comparison based sorting takes at best O(n * log(n)) time, iterating over the array will take O(n) time for n elements in the array.

A pragmatical solution would be to use NSArray#containsObject if you already know the object.

Otherwise you have to implement your own comparison strategy and step through the array

Answer (score -1):

you can use fast enumeration.
eg:

NSEnumerator *enumerator = [set objectEnumerator];

```
NSNumber *setObject ;

while ((setObject = [enumerator nextObject]) != nil){


    [gids appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[setObject intValue]]];

}
```

Comment: This just tells how to loop. It has nothing to do with searching.